# Class 'App\Proyect' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I am developing web based on proyects using laravel 5.5 when I execute http://127.0.0.1:8000/proyectos occurred following error.

[Class 'App\Proyect' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW3Sz.png)

```
namespace IntelabProyect\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Proyect;

class FrontController extends Controller
{

    public function welcome()
    {
        //retorno de la vista
        return view('welcome');

    }
    /*public function nosotros()
    {
        //retorno de la vista
        return view('nosotros');
    }*/

    public function proyectos()
    {
        $proyects = Proyect::paginate(10);
        //retorno de la vista
        return view('proyectos')->with(compact('proyects'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you declare that namespace.

Comment: `namespace IntelabProyect\Http\Controllers;` implies that your root namespace is called `IntelabProyect` not `App`. Try `use IntelabProyect\Proyect;`

Comment: This is just a guess, but shouldn't your usage be like `App\Project` not Pro**y**ect

Comment: Can you add your route ?

Comment: @apokryfos It works! Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have changed Laravel default `App` namespace to `IntelabProyect`. You might need to try following things,

1. Change `use App\Proyect;` to `use IntelabProyect\Proyect;` on the controller.
2. Make sure `Proyect` class declared inside `IntelabProyect` namespace (not `App`).
3. The file is located under `app` directory and its name is exactly `Proyect.php`